# Is HTTPS slower than HTTP?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I think about put my all www throught SSL
Is https slower than http?
How exactly it work I mean technically,

Is all data between server and client is encrypted?
If so this would consume a lot of server CPU if must encrypt all served data in the fly before send to client.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really broad question and answering it properly is well beyond this simple question and answers format.

What typically requires most CPU performance is in establishing the HTTPS session, the [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), after which a simple and low cost symmetric encryption scheme can be used.

In nearly every real world scenario the CPU overhead of using HTTPS, or rather TLS, is negligable compared to everything else your servers will be computing.